# Sorting multiple items at the same time using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to setup a way to sort multiple items at the same time using [jQuery UI's Sortable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/). I have come up with a partial solution, where the checked items go with the drag, but I can't get them all to move positions. Here is what I have: http://jsbin.com/ecela

What do I need to add to ensure the items move to their new location and get removed when dragging starts.

Also, I'm wondering if there is a way to use selectable and sortable together. I'm guessing not because they both require you to click on the items to select and drag/sort them.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/shvetsgroup/jquery.multisortable

Comment: That's pretty much what I was looking for. It's a little weird that you can drag a main item in the middle of sub items.
Put this as an answer so you can get some up votes :)

Answer (score 3):

There's a jQuery plugin for that: [multisortable](https://github.com/shvetsgroup/jquery.multisortable).

They have a jsfiddle example there too. You select items with shift-click or command-click, then drag them around.

Seems like a good starting off point, at least!